# How to find the monotony and the convergence of this function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> I have to find the  monotony and the convergence of
>   $$a_{n+1} = 2\frac{1+a_{n}}{3+a_{n}}$$
>   for every $n \in\mathbb N$ when $0<a_{1}<2$

What I have done is:

I said that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists and is equal to a number $l$, then 
$$\begin{align*}
l&=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}\\
 &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2\frac{1+a_{n}}{3+a_{n}}\right)\\
 &=2\cdot\frac{1+\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}}{3+\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}}\\
 &=2\cdot\frac{1+l}{3+l}\\
\Leftrightarrow l & = 2\cdot\frac{1+l}{3+l}\\
\Leftrightarrow 3l+l^2 &=2+2l\\
\Leftrightarrow l^2+l-2 &=0
\end{align*}$$

And from here I find that $l=1$ and $l=-2$. But, since $0<a_{1}<2$ I reject the negative solution. Thus $l=1$.

From here on I don't know how to continue. I have solved a couple of similar exercises, but on them I was given a number for $a_{1}$. So I used inductive reasoning (not sure if this is the right expression) and I found the monotony of the function.

The way I used the inductive reasoning is:

- I saw that for $n=1$ the statement was true
- I supposed it was true for $n$ and then proved that it was true for $n+1$.

But since I don't have a number for $a_{1}$ I can't continue.

Any tips?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should help you with the equations. A limit is `\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n` and multiplication sign is `\cdot`, because `*` has a different meaning in mathematics.

Comment: Try comparing a[k] with a[k+1] via: a[k+1] - a[k] and see if the value is greater than 0.  Note: You should probably expect the result to be greater than 0 when a[k] is *less than* your limit, and less than 0 when a[k] is *greater than* your limit.  You will need to consider what happens when a[k] is in the region (0, 1) and when it is in the region (1, 2).  You have an expression for a[k+1] in terms of a[k], so this should help in setting up the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  solved it after all. I  took three cases for the $a_{n}$.

The cases where:

- $a_{1}<1$
- $a_{1}=1$
- $a_{1}>1$

For $a_{1}<1$:

I found (per @Bill Province's comment) that the function is monotonically increasing and that $a_{k}<1$. Thus it is convergent.

For $a_{1}=1$:

I found that $a_{k}=1$, thus it is convergent.

For $a_{1}>1$:

I found that $a_{k}>1$. Τhus the $(a_{n})$ has a lower bound; it also is monotonically increasing -> thus is is not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
To rule out $l = -2$ you must have $0<a_n<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. You induction step is thus
$$0<a_n<2 \Rightarrow 0<a_{n+1}<2$$
It's easy to show an even stronger bound: $0<a_n<2 \Rightarrow \frac25 <a_{n+1}<2$, you should come across this naturally when trying to prove it.

Comment: And how do I continue from this induction step? I'm sure how

Comment: This proves $0\le \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\le 2$ immediately (note that the borders $0$ and $2$ are included.